# Wordpress theme development : Call to undefined function WP_Query()

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I'm developing my own Wordpress theme and I have this issue "***Call to undefined function WP_Query()***" with my functions.php file while trying to get my Custom posts ("event").

I already tried to add include('wp-load.php') but did not change anything.

Did anyone already have the same issue ?
Already did some researches but did not find anything that solved my problem.

Here is my simple code :

```
$argsEvents = array('post_type'  => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => '-1');

$result = WP_Query( $argsEvents );

if ( $result->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $result->have_posts() ) {

        $result->the_post();

        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    wp_reset_postdata();

} else echo "No data";
```

Thanks a lot for you help!

Gillian

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using **new** before calling **WP_Query**.

Change:

```
$result = WP_Query( $argsEvents );
```

To:

```
$result = new WP_Query( $argsEvents );
```

Comment: Simple as that... Can't believe it, thanks a lot :-)